# Only last line is being written into a file

Tags: java, printwriter

I need HELP. I tried to separate the valid serial keys from invalid ones. I got the output correctly. but then when i tried to write it in a file, ONLY the last line is being written.
the output is:

1A000000
1A000001
1A000002
1A000003
1A000004
1A000005
2B200012
3C343455
4D342423
5E324344
6F435435
7G245347

and I want to write this to a file. But ONLY 7G245347 is being written.

```
import java.util.*;`
import java.io.*;
public class ValidSerialKey {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String keys = "";

        File file = new File("serialkeys.txt");
        try{        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);        
            while (scan.hasNext()){
                keys = scan.nextLine();

               if ((keys.charAt(0) == '1' || keys.charAt(0) == '2' || keys.charAt(0) == '3' || keys.charAt(0) == '4' || keys.charAt(0) == '5' || 
                    keys.charAt(0) == '6' || keys.charAt(0) == '7' || keys.charAt(0) == '8' || keys.charAt(0) == '9' ) && 
                   (keys.charAt(1) == 'A' || keys.charAt(1) == 'B' || keys.charAt(1) == 'C' || keys.charAt(1) == 'D' || keys.charAt(1) == 'E' || 
                    keys.charAt(1) == 'F' || keys.charAt(1) == 'G' || keys.charAt(1) == 'H' || keys.charAt(1) == 'I' || keys.charAt(1) == 'J' ||
                    keys.charAt(1) == 'K' || keys.charAt(1) == 'L' || keys.charAt(1) == 'M' || keys.charAt(1) == 'N' || keys.charAt(1) == 'O' ||
                    keys.charAt(1) == 'P' || keys.charAt(1) == 'Q' || keys.charAt(1) == 'R' || keys.charAt(1) == 'S' || keys.charAt(1) == 'T' ||
                    keys.charAt(1) == 'U' || keys.charAt(1) == 'V' || keys.charAt(1) == 'W' || keys.charAt(1) == 'X' || keys.charAt(1) == 'Y' ||
                    keys.charAt(1) == 'Z' )){

                    System.out.println(keys);

                    File filein = new File("ValidKeys.txt");
                    try{
                        try
                           (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filein)){
                               pw.print(keys);
                               pw.close();
                        }
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }


               }//end of if             
            }//end of while
            scan.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException exp){
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep reopening the same file in a loop... without asking to append the file.

Comment: For your validaton problem. Please upadte your condition. A character is a numerical value, so you can check for interval [0-9] like `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`, same is done with letter [a-z] like `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'`.

Comment: Thanks! my code now runs perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to write files simultaneously? I already written the valid serials in a file. what if I also had to write the invalid serials into another file.

Comment: What would be the problem to declare to `PrintWriter` ?

Comment: yes, i'm having a problem with `PrintWriter`

Comment: Please be more broad ... what problem are you having ? You are out of topic here. If you can't find an answer with Google, post a new answer. This as nothing to do with a append that don't work I guess

Comment: I did thanks. just a little manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep the `PrintWriter` opened to write other things during the next iterations of the loop
So don't create a new one at each iteration.

As a side note, you don't need to close explicitly  the `PrintWriter` instance when you use `try with resources`.

You should replace this logic :

```
loop     
    try
       (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(uniqueFile)){
           pw.print(keys);             
    }//end of inner try

end loop
```

by a logic where you include the whole logic in the `try with resources` statement :

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(uniqueFile)){
    loop  
        pw.print(keys);                       
    end loop
}
catch (IOException e){ 
   ... // exception handling
}
```

Comment: This will work only once, you closed the `PrintWriter` in the loop. This should be done outside of the loop.

Comment: Right. Thank you :) I am thinking about your comment and a better way to address the problem. I updated. Finally `try with resources` is suitable. What do you think of this version ?

Comment: Depends if OP want to break the loop on the exception. I would keep the try-with-resource like you did, but catch some exception inside it (`PrintWriter.append` don't specified any, so in your case, is there a risk ? not sure). But we could prevent a loop breaking based on the input of the user (Scanner) (But I am thinking to much here ;) )

Comment: "Depends if OP want to break the loop on the exception." In fact, only the `PrintWriter()` constructor declares throwing a `FileNotFoundException`. So, we will get the exception soon. If  `FileNotFoundException` is throws, looping makes no really sense.

Comment: "PrintWriter.append don't specified any, so in your case, is there a risk ? not sure" Indeed `PrintWriter` methods don't throw I/O exceptions, but some of its constructors do. For example in the `write(String)` method , you can see : `catch (IOException x) {
            trouble = true;
        }`

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember that boolean logic now (so do we rethrow it if needed ?), so indeed it is safe to use like this (unless user input something bad in the original code). So definitly, I would use your actual code ;)